# jQuery onClick: How to add class to element and remove from all others

Tags: javascript, jquery

You will have to excuse a probably very basic question as I am still getting to grips with jQuery.

I've set up this code so that on click of the .team-member figure elememt, a class called 'overlayOn' is added which adds an absolutely positioned div with an rbga colour (anyway I digress).

This works perfectly, except I want it so that on click of an element it adds the 'overlayOn' class and disables the others.
Now I know this should be a simple case of removeClass, or toggleClass but I cannot for the life of me get this working. The annoying thing is I have actually done this before but cannot see where I am going wrong this time.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
// Store the references outside the event handler
 var $window = jQuery(window);
 var $memberItem = ".team-member figure";
 function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    console.log(windowsize);
    if (windowsize < 768) {
        // if the window is smaller than 768px then allow click to see overlay
      jQuery($memberItem).click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                jQuery(this).toggleClass('overlayOn');
      });
  }
}

// Execute on load
checkWidth();

// Bind event listener
jQuery(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

});

Updated: Below is my code from the suggestions given, when clicking on an element now it will remove the class from others but if I want to click on an element with the overlayOn class to remove it from itself it will not work.

My updated code is below.

```
jQuery(".team-member figure").click(function (event) {
  var $window = jQuery(window);
  var windowsize = $window.width();
  if (windowsize < 768) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.team-member figure').removeClass('overlayOn');
      $(this).toggleClass('overlayOn');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `window.width()` inside the click event itself. `$('.overlayOn').removeClass('overlayOn');` will help you to remove a the class name                     `overlayOn` from all the elements. Then you can add `overlayOn` to the current object using `.addClass()` method

```
jQuery(".team-member figure").click(function (event) {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize < 768) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.overlayOn').removeClass('overlayOn');
        $(this).addClass('overlayOn');
    }
});
```

**Edit**

```
    jQuery(".team-member figure").click(function (event) {
  var $window = jQuery(window);
  var windowsize = $window.width();
  if (windowsize < 768) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.overlayOn').not(this).removeClass('overlayOn');
      $(this).toggleClass('overlayOn');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion of bringing the window size inside the function, I have done this, this has fixed one issue and created another though, please see my other comment.

Comment: @MichaelWeaver where is the comment?

Comment: Ah sorry, I've updated the code in the main question, it wouldn't let me paste the code with the comment itself.

Comment: that worked perfectly, I'd never heard of the.not() function before - thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.removeClass()` to remove class `overlayOn` from all `.team-member figure` and only add this class to clicked `figure`:

```
jQuery($memberItem).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.team-member figure').removeClass('overlayOn');
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('overlayOn');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. As mentioned above, this has helped and I have changed addClass to toggleClass as per your suggestion. However now when I use the following code, when I click on an element it will remove the class from others but when I click on the element with OverlayOn to remove it from itself it doesnt work (I hope this makes sense).