# jQuery: Toggle class on one element, remove same from all other

Tags: javascript, jquery

new here and deeply hoping I'm not missing a stupid syntax flaw. I was thinking that my problem is a fairly common one, but somehow nothing has helped so far in my specific case. 
There is a simple inline-block list of Image Galleries which are zoomable to fill the parent width. As soon as one is zoomed through click on a child, the others should unzoom by stripping of the class which maximizes them. Nothing more to it.
I achieved the first part via the following jQuery (where the problem is hidden in the for-loop, I think):

```js
  $(".zoom").click(function() {
    var target = $(this);
    target.closest('div.product-item').toggleClass('maximized');

    var ot = document.getElementsByClassName('product-item');
    for (var i = 0; i < ot.length; i++) {
      if (ot[i] !== target) {
        ot[i].removeClass('maximized');
      }
    }
  });
```

So: Some .zoom classed element is clicked, its parent is toggled to maximize and a for loop checks all other elements of the same class as the parent and removes the .maximized class.
The reason the script is constructed with a for-loop and a removeClass is so that the same .zoom elements are able to minimize their parent elements, not only to maximize them.

Im not a javascript professional, but to my knowledge this should work in principle. Am I missing anything here?

This post from a year ago addressed a similar problem but didn't help in my case: [jQuery onClick: How to add class to element and remove from all others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791513/jquery-onclick-how-to-add-class-to-element-and-remove-from-all-others)

[You can find a pen to see the script in action here.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVVqNo?editors=001)

Comment: You cant compare objects like this `ot[i] != target`

Comment: Yes, true, edited. But it still doesn't work with the correct operator. Thanks :)

Comment: You're calling `removeClass()` on a dom object, not a jquery object. Try `$(ot).not(target).removeClass('maximized');`

Comment: That is good to know thanks. Plus, I didn't know about the .not() Method, awesome! Still, would this be correct? `$document.getElementsByClassName('product-item').not(target).removeClass('maximized');` It somehow doesn't work either. I tried your version with or without the for loop (The API Doc say without if I'm reading correctly) but still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".zoom").on('click',function() {
    var target = $(this);
    $('div.product-item').removeClass('maximized');
    target.closest('div.product-item').toggleClass('maximized');
});
```

you can use

```
if(target.closest('div.product-item').hasClass('maximized')){
      $('div.product-item').removeClass('maximized');
  }else{
      $('div.product-item').removeClass('maximized');
          target.closest('div.product-item').addClass('maximized');
  }
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yfyr64La/)

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately that doesn't work, because then you cannot use the .zoom element to minimize its parent. Parent is maxed >> You Click >> parent is minimized by .removeClass >> parent is maximized by toggleClass.

Comment: @lthz  you can see updated answer  hope it help .. and you can use the same concept for ('rotated')  inside the same if statement

Comment: Was stuck in my code. So simple yet so good. Thanks big time, works in every way.